# Vue component for increment,decrement or enter a number into input

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am new to VueJS and I love it, but sometimes it gets a bit complicated if I use components.
I have got a shopping cart and I would like to use increment/decrement or user can enter a specific number of items inside the input box.

The issue is Vue keeps complaining that the child element can't modify the parent data. I tired different ways but it is not working

**This is my component**

```
Vue.component('product-counter', {
props: ['quantity'],
data: function () {
    return {
        count: this.quantity
    }
},
template: `<div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="$emit('increment-quantity'); " class="btn btn-success" > <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input v-model="quantity" v-on:input="$emit('input', quantity)" class="form-control" >
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="$emit('decrement-quantity');" v-bind:disabled="quantity<1" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
})
```

**This is my HTML code calls Component**

```
 <product-counter v-bind:quantity="item.quan" v-on:input="item.quan=$event" v-on:increment-quantity="item.quan++" v-on:decrement-quantity="item.quan--" ></product-counter>
```

Increment and Decrement works perfectly but if you enter a number into input, i am getting this error:

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value
> will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead,
> use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "quantity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to a prop using `v-model`. One option is to watch for the `quantity` prop and bind to `count` instead:

```js
Vue.component('product-counter', {
  props: ['quantity'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      count: this.quantity
    }
  },
  watch: {
    quantity(val) {
      this.count = val;
    }
  },
  template: `<div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="$emit('increment-quantity'); " class="btn btn-success" > <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input v-model="count" v-on:input="$emit('input', count)" class="form-control" >
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="$emit('decrement-quantity');" v-bind:disabled="quantity<1" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: {
      quan: 0
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <product-counter v-bind:quantity="item.quan" v-on:input="item.quan=$event" v-on:increment-quantity="item.quan++" v-on:decrement-quantity="item.quan--"></product-counter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `v-model` on prop. Use combination of `:value=` and `@input`.

1. As you are already handling the event, just replace `v-model="quantity"` with `v-bind:value="quantity"`
2. Don't emit the event with value of `quantity` prop, but new value send by `input` element. Instead of `v-on:input="$emit('input', quantity)"` use `v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`

### Why

`v-model="quantity"` is syntactic sugar for `v-bind:value="quantity" v-on:input="quantity = $event.target.value"`)

Such handler is problem if used on prop because props are [one way only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) - only parent who "owns" the value should change it. So we are replacing `v-on:input="quantity = $event.target.value"` with `v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value"`

`v-on:input="$emit('input', quantity)"` will not send new changed value, but "old" value...

### Even better

...is to use `computed`. The code:

```js
Vue.component('product-counter', {
  props: ['value'],
  computed: {
    count: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('input', newValue) }
    }
  },
  template: `<div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="count++" class="btn btn-success" > <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input v-model.number="count" class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <button v-on:click="count--" v-bind:disabled="count<1" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: {
      quan: 0
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <product-counter v-model="item.quan"></product-counter>
  <div> {{ item.quan }}</div>
</div>
```